# Can i setup cluster for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cluster, clustering

I have two computers, both crummy ones, one is Celeron with two cores 2.2. second one is Pentium 4 with one core, both with 2 GB of ram. now what i want to achieve is that to use that second one to speed up my Celeron PC. i want to have windows 7 on Celeron i can install any necessary OS on second one. So basically my question is: is this possible? can i speed up my Celeron like that? Celeron has 2 cores Pentium has 1 core now could they work as fast as 3 cores and 4 GB of ram? or just faster than two cores. And if thats possible than is it worth doing it? i mean how faster will CPU be e.g. 10% 20% etc.

Those who downvote this thread, could you please also explain what is problem with this question? I have zero knowledge in clustering and I'm a newbie at superuser so maybe i have bad understanding of something and would be nice to know whats problem with my question.

Comment: They would burn more in electricity than you would gain. I'd bite the bullet & pick up something newer from a junk shop. Plan on about 10 quid/bucks/shekels being about all you'd need to spend to beat those 2 machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) is for [massively parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_parallel_(computing)) computing tasks. In order to take advantage of clustering, you would need to be running specific software designed to do so. You will gain no performance improvement on normal computer tasks.

There are certainly ways to take advantage of multiple computers for normal tasks - screen sharing, remote terminals, software KVM - but clustering is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the downvotes.  Maybe a kind of vague question for some but tips should be given to new users. **A bit of a duplicate question.**

There is a thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039039/create-a-cluster-of-co-workers-windows-7-pcs-for-parallel-processing-in-r) that talks about clustering Win 7 PC's with doRedis to queue jobs on another machine.

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/165134/3-4-old-computers-general-purpose-cluster?rq=1) talks about using X11(Mac server OS) but I'm not sure that will work with your processors.

It sounds like any Linux OS will allow a fairly easy cluster.  Sorry I don't have more for ya.  This [Beowulf Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster) info.  As TJL said, you won't see much difference, biggest thing would probably be running process X on the other computer and keeping that bit of resource available locally.

Answer (score -4):

I imagine the OP's question was based more on curiosity than anything else; to downvote is like yelling at a child for learning to read. Just saying. Someone will probably downvote me for pointing that out, go figure...

Anyhow, I remember reading there's some experimental work with OpenStack and Grid Computing. Now let's say you were able to create a stable 64bit Windows 7 image running on OpenStack Grid environment.  It would be total chaos, due to the unstable nature of Microsoft OS in general. Windows just Sucks at this kind of stuff! I imagine with some persistence, it could be done.

Here are couple resource links about install Win7 on OpenStack:
[Deploy Windows 7 to OpenStack - Windows Setup Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/588126/deploy-windows-7-to-openstack-windows-setup-error-when-instance-boots)
[Windows image for OpenStack](https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/windows-image-for-openstack/)

However, the above is only for a common image similar to running from ESXi/VMware, to get it to recognize a massively parallel node system you probably have to spend every single moment of time writing custom drivers to make it work and that is a Big IF.

It'd be much easier to create a custom Linux distro/Windows clone to do this. I would start by creating a small Raspberry Pi cluster then maybe move on to something like Qlustar or Beowulf, once you learn, then try to see if anything Windows-based would be a good choice.

Comment: Your answer would receive a much better response if you stick to just the technical facts that address the question.  The extensive commentary detracts and isn't really relevant on a Q&A site.